# Variable column lines changed when ode45 function process?

Tags: matlab, math

I wonder why when I run my code as below, the variable `y` will change from 2*2 to 4*1?

```
function testforleader()   
    %tspan=[0 10];
    %y0=[[10 10];[3 3]];
    y = zeros(2)
    [t,y] = ode45('leadermove',[0 10],[10 10;3 3]);

function ydotr=leadermove(t,y)
    y
    ydotr = [y(2,:);[sin(t) cos(t)]];
```

The message in the command windows will show like this:

> y =

```
 0     0
 0     0
```

> y =

```
10
 3
10
 3
```

and then the function ode45 seems only receive the **one** column vector of variable `y`?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `ode45` does not have `y` on the rhs:

```
[t,y]=ode45('leadermove',[0 10],[10 10;3 3]);
```

but on the lhs. If it exists before the call it will be overwritten by the call.  Perhaps you ought to rename the variable on the lhs to something like `yout` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your leadermove function doesn't work for me, so I can't test this. I think the third argument to [ode45](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ode23.html) should be a vector, so maybe changing it to:

```
[t,y]=ode45('leadermove',[0 10],[10 10 3 3]);
```

will fix it. Also, as Mark says,

```
y = zeros(2);
```

doesn't do anything because ode45 will overwrite it when it returns an output. You might be able to fix this with:

```
y = zeros(2);
[t,y(:)]=ode45('leadermove',[0 10],[10 10 3 3]);
```

but I don't know if that would work, and I suspect that the way you are calling ode45 now is giving you the wrong answer anyway.

Comment: Well, I should not post the code y=zeros(2); it didn't affect the code process below. Actually, the initial value of y is [10 10;3 3]. But as it showed above, it will turn into a one column vector [10;3;10;3], before the error message showed.